# passing HashMap with bundle returning null

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I am attempting to pass a `HashMap` to another `fragment` via `bundle`. However my `bundle` is returning `null`.

I create the `bundle` with this

```
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        // dismiss the dialog
        pDialog.dismiss();
        int a = 0;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Fragment fragment = new Assessment_Fragment();
        for (int i = 0; i < infoList.size(); i++) {
            // get HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = infoList.get(i);
            // autoincremented key for retreiving as many HashMaps as needed
            bundle.putSerializable("" + a, map); 
            // so i will know how many hashmaps exist
            bundle.putInt("key", a);
            // increment key
            a++;
        }

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    };
```

This is how I receive the `bundle`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_assessment, container, false);
        // check for values
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            // application never gets here !
            int a = getArguments().getInt("key");

            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) getArguments()
                        .getSerializable("" + i);

                if (map.get(TAG_FIELD).equals(r)) {...
```

The application doesn't crash, there are no errors. This `fragment` simply never inflates because the `bundle` is never `!= null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is the FragmentTransaction? the AsyncTask runs inside an Activity?

Comment: ... i must of deleted it and not even realized. *face palm*

Comment: @blackbelt post the fragment transaction as an answer and I will accept, sorry for the stupidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onPostExecute()` you have to replace or add the fragment through a FragmentTransaction:

```
 Fragment newFragment = CountingFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, fragment).commit();
```

also you can avoid to iterate through your infoList to get and put every HashMap inside the bunde. You can put directly infoList

Comment: I saw a way to pass the infoList as  `putParcelableArrayList` but it didn't quite make sense to me. Since `HashMaps` are by default serializable I just went with this. If you are feeling generous you can post the code I would need for that as well. =)

Comment: use putSerializable("key", infoList);

Comment: =( your kidding, I was trying to pass it off as `putParcelableArrayList` and it was giving me all kinds of grief.